# How to make the video size match the window size

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-media-player

I'm making an intro to my app.I have two such smaller questions.

- I would like the video to be as big as the window,in short to fit.

[image: I'd like to see only the video, not the bar and be fullscreen]

- How to insert a video into WinForm so that the play bar,sound bar
  etc is not visible.

Comment: Dock = Fill, uiMode = "none".  Beware of a bug, the uiMode property must explicitly be set in code, after the InitializeComponent() method call.

Comment: @HansPassant uiMode property should I set what width I want?

Comment: `uiMode` specifies how the WMP Interface is presented, the `Dock` Property its UI layout. Just add these settings in the Form's Constructor. E.g., `public SomeForm() { InitializeComponent(); [YourPlayer].uiMode = "none"; [YourPlayer].Dock = DockStyle.Fill; }` -- You can of course anchor the WMP component instead, or set a specific size (the DpiAwareness mode counts here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, just edited to

```
Dock = Fill, uiMode = "none"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).